# Problem with editing single.php file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I downloaded the single.php file to customize a specific single posts page in WordPress. I was using shortcodes in a fashion similar to this:
`echo do_shortcode("[av_section ...][/av_section]");`

On the normal pages, I typically used the Advanced Layout Editor. However, if I want a specific shortcode (say for a template banner I created), I go into the Default mode and grab the shortcode. Then I plug in this shortcode into the single.php file.

Note: I am using WordPress's FTP to work locally and then push back up to the remote file on WordPress.

For the purpose of this question, I simplified my code (sorry, it's still a little long).

```
<?php
    if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )    { die(); }

    global $avia_config;

    /*
     * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
     */
    get_header();


    $title  = __('Blog - Latest News', 'avia_framework'); //default blog title
    $t_link = home_url('/');
    $t_sub = '';

    if( avia_get_option( 'frontpage' ) && $new = avia_get_option( 'blogpage' ) )
    {
        $title = get_the_title( $new ); //if the blog is attached to a page use this title
        $t_link = get_permalink( $new );
        $t_sub = avia_post_meta( $new, 'subtitle' );
    }

    if( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'header', true ) != 'no' )
    {
        echo avia_title( array( 'heading' => 'strong', 'title' => $title, 'link' => $t_link, 'subtitle' => $t_sub ) );
    }

    do_action( 'ava_after_main_title' );

?>

        <div class='container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color <?php avia_layout_class( 'main' ); ?>'>

            <div class='container template-blog template-single-blog '>

                <main class='content units <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?> <?php echo avia_blog_class_string(); ?>' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'post'));?>>

<?php 
    if (is_singular('team')) {
?>
        
<!-- Page Banner Container -->
<?php
    /* Store page side titles */
    $array = array(
        "Dr. Jason Adams" => "Vice President/president-elect",
        "Dr. Beth Mulvey" => "Secretary/treasurer",
        "Dr. Jody Wood" => "Executive Director",
        "Dr. Chris Templeton" => "Past President",
        "Dr. Jeanette Westfall" => "President",
        "Dr. Eric Flack" => "Kansas City Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Montize Aaron" => "St. Louis Regional Representative",
        "Jennifer Vandeven" => "Southeast Missouri Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Greg Carter" => "South Central Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Deana Ogden" => "Representative From the Missouri State Teacher Association",
        "Samantha Hayes" => "Representative From the Missouri National Education Association",
        "Julie Blaine" => "Representative From the Regional Professional Development Centers",
        "Dr. Tim Roth" => "Heart of Missouri Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Glenna Bult" => "Central Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Bobbie Jo Lewis" => "Representative From the Missouri Department of Elementary and Secondary Education",
        "Dr. Garrett Lowder" => "Southwest Area Regional Representative",
        "Valerie Pierce" => "Northwest Area Regional Representative",
        "Dr. Stacy Quinn" => "Northeast Area Regional Representative"
    );
                
    /* Get Page Title */
    $title = get_the_title();
    
    /* Get Subtitle */
    $subtitle = $array[$title];
    
    
    echo do_shortcode("[av_section min_height='' min_height_pc='25' min_height_px='500px' shadow='no-border-styling' bottom_border='no-border-styling' bottom_border_diagonal_color='#333333' bottom_border_diagonal_direction='' bottom_border_style='' padding='default' custom_margin='0px' custom_margin_sync='true' av-desktop-custom_margin='' av-desktop-custom_margin_sync='true' av-medium-custom_margin='' av-medium-custom_margin_sync='true' av-small-custom_margin='' av-small-custom_margin_sync='true' av-mini-custom_margin='' av-mini-custom_margin_sync='true' svg_div_top='' svg_div_top_color='#333333' svg_div_top_width='100' svg_div_top_height='50' svg_div_top_max_height='none' svg_div_top_opacity='' svg_div_bottom='' svg_div_bottom_color='#333333' svg_div_bottom_width='100' svg_div_bottom_height='50' svg_div_bottom_max_height='none' svg_div_bottom_opacity='' color='main_color' background='bg_color' custom_bg='' background_gradient_direction='vertical' background_gradient_color1='#000000' background_gradient_color2='#ffffff' background_gradient_color3='' src='https://staging4.learningforwardmo.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/background.jpeg' attachment='1864' attachment_size='medium' attach='scroll' position='center center' repeat='stretch' video='' video_ratio='16:9' overlay_enable='aviaTBoverlay_enable' overlay_opacity='0.8' overlay_color='#2a7dc8' overlay_pattern='' overlay_custom_pattern='' custom_arrow_bg='' css_position_z_index='' av-desktop-css_position_z_index='' av-medium-css_position_z_index='' av-small-css_position_z_index='' av-mini-css_position_z_index='' id='' custom_class='page-banner' template_class='centercols' aria_label='' av_element_hidden_in_editor='0' av_uid='av-5ghi9d' sc_version='1.0'] [av_two_third first min_height='' vertical_alignment='av-align-top' space='' row_boxshadow='' row_boxshadow_width='10' row_boxshadow_color='' custom_margin='' margin='0px' av-desktop-margin='' av-medium-margin='' av-small-margin='' av-mini-margin='' mobile_breaking='' mobile_column_order='' border='' border_style='solid' border_color='' radius='' min_col_height='' padding='' av-desktop-padding='' av-medium-padding='' av-small-padding='' av-mini-padding='' svg_div_top='' svg_div_top_color='#333333' svg_div_top_width='100' svg_div_top_height='50' svg_div_top_max_height='none' svg_div_top_flip='' svg_div_top_invert='' svg_div_top_front='' svg_div_top_opacity='' svg_div_top_preview='' svg_div_bottom='' svg_div_bottom_color='#333333' svg_div_bottom_width='100' svg_div_bottom_height='50' svg_div_bottom_max_height='none' svg_div_bottom_flip='' svg_div_bottom_invert='' svg_div_bottom_front='' svg_div_bottom_opacity='' svg_div_bottom_preview='' column_boxshadow='' column_boxshadow_width='10' column_boxshadow_color='' background='bg_color' background_color='' background_gradient_direction='vertical' background_gradient_color1='#000000' background_gradient_color2='#ffffff' background_gradient_color3='' src='' background_position='top left' background_repeat='no-repeat' highlight='' highlight_size='' animation='' animation_duration='' animation_custom_bg_color='' animation_z_index_curtain='100' parallax_parallax='' parallax_parallax_speed='' av-desktop-parallax_parallax='' av-desktop-parallax_parallax_speed='' av-medium-parallax_parallax='' av-medium-parallax_parallax_speed='' av-small-parallax_parallax='' av-small-parallax_parallax_speed='' av-mini-parallax_parallax='' av-mini-parallax_parallax_speed='' css_position='' css_position_location='' css_position_z_index='' av-desktop-css_position='' av-desktop-css_position_location='' av-desktop-css_position_z_index='' av-medium-css_position='' av-medium-css_position_location='' av-medium-css_position_z_index='' av-small-css_position='' av-small-css_position_location='' av-small-css_position_z_index='' av-mini-css_position='' av-mini-css_position_location='' av-mini-css_position_z_index='' link='' linktarget='' link_hover='' title_attr='' alt_attr='' mobile_display='' mobile_col_pos='0' id='' custom_class='' template_class='' aria_label='' av_uid='av-3uuqwh' sc_version='1.0'] [av_textblock textblock_styling_align='center' textblock_styling='' textblock_styling_gap='' textblock_styling_mobile='' size='' av-desktop-font-size='' av-medium-font-size='' av-small-font-size='' av-mini-font-size='' font_color='custom' color='#ffffff' id='' custom_class='' template_class='' av_uid='av-l850o57c' sc_version='1.0' admin_preview_bg='']<h1 style='text-align: center;'>$title</h1>[/av_textblock] [av_hr class='default' icon_select='yes' icon='ue808' font='entypo-fontello' position='center' shadow='no-shadow' height='50' custom_border='av-border-thin' custom_width='50px' custom_margin_top='30px' custom_margin_bottom='30px' custom_border_color='' custom_icon_color='' id='' custom_class='' template_class='' av_uid='av-2ehgj5' sc_version='1.0' admin_preview_bg=''][/av_hr] [av_textblock textblock_styling_align='' textblock_styling='' textblock_styling_gap='' textblock_styling_mobile='' size='15' av-desktop-font-size='' av-medium-font-size='' av-small-font-size='' av-mini-font-size='' font_color='custom' color='#ffffff' id='' custom_class='' template_class='' av_uid='av-l850oeeg' sc_version='1.0' admin_preview_bg=''] <p style='text-align: center;'>$subtitle</p> [/av_textblock]   [/av_two_third] [/av_section]");
?>
                    
<?php
    } else {
?>
                    
                    <?php
                    /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                    * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                    * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
                    *
                    */
                        /*get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'index' );

                        $blog_disabled = ( avia_get_option('disable_blog') == 'disable_blog' ) ? true : false;

                        if( ! $blog_disabled )
                        {
                            //show related posts based on tags if there are any
                            get_template_part( 'includes/related-posts' );

                            //wordpress function that loads the comments template "comments.php"
                            comments_template();
                        }*/
                    ?>
                    
<?php
    }
?>

                <!--end content-->
                </main>

                <?php
                $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'blog';
                //get the sidebar
                get_sidebar();


                ?>


            </div><!--end container-->

        </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->


<?php
        get_footer();
```

The problem is that my short codes don't seem to close properly, and they grab the following elements. For example, see how the page-banner grabs the footer in this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTBu-ODP8XprfYc4YCmMzBHMMWHP3XtE/view?usp=sharing

I appreciate your time greatly,

- Nathan

NOTE: The overall theme is that I want to take this element which I designed in the Advanced Layout Editor (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gSK_BMfrAP_aLZdKtwOGLAkO7XzGsfnr/view?usp=sharing) and insert it in my custom template using PHP. A solution that generates shortcode or HTML should be sufficient, I just don't know what the easiest way is without completely redesigning it in HTML, which while possible seems to be an inefficient solution.

Comment: Great hat. Thing is, we don't really know where to look at or what you modified, bear in mind that people on SO are not sitting next to you... What have you modify in your template, where should we look ? Be a bit more precise on what should be the end result. What is not "normal" in your example where "the shortcode doesn't seems to close properly" ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @amarinediary ! My main question can be seen at my note at the bottom. NOTE: The overall theme is that I want to take this element which I designed in the Advanced Layout Editor (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gSK_BMfrAP_aLZdKtwOGLAkO7XzGsfnr/view?usp=sharing) and insert it in my custom template using PHP. A solution that generates shortcode or HTML should be sufficient, I just don't know what the easiest way is without completely redesigning it in HTML, which while possible seems to be an inefficient solution.

Comment: So the exact specifics of my situation is not so much my worry. But is there a good strategy to getting the shortcode OR HTML code from the Advanced Layout Builder and translating that into PHP / HTML code? Thanks for your time!